# Django Template Does Not Exist at /

Tags: django, url, web-applications

So i have this in my urls.py file

```
urlpatterns = [
    url('^$', IndexView.as_view(), name='index'),
]
```

And my view is as follows:

```
class IndexView(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'index.html'

    @method_decorator(ensure_csrf_cookie, name="dispatch")
    def dispatch(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return super(IndexView, self).dispatch(*args, **kwargs)
```

But when i hit the link localhost:8000/ I get an error saying:-

```
raise TemplateDoesNotExist(', '.join(template_name_list), chain=chain)
TemplateDoesNotExist: index.html
```

Comment: As the error says, Django cannot find the `index.html`. We can't help any more than that, because you haven't show your template settings or the layout of your template files. The full error message will list the directories that Django searched for `index.html`.